# java mostrar el promedio

Tags: java, bluej

me encargaron realizar este programa en bluej y todo va muy bien, me atore en la parte de sumar, sacar y mostrar el promedio no se como realizar esa parte y me vendría bien un poco de ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código hasta el momento, lo único que me falta es mostrar el promedio y como dije no pude hacerlo, se agradece mucho la ayuda.

```
public class Estudiantes
{
   static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static double [] cargacalif(double [] calificaciones)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++)
       {
           System.out.print(" Ingresa la calificaion ");
           calificaciones[i]= lector.nextDouble();
       }
       return calificaciones;
   }

   public static void muestracalifs(double [] calificaciones)
   {
       System.out.println("\nCalificaciones");
       for(int i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++)
       {
           System.out.print(calificaciones[i] + " ");
       }
   }

   public static void sumacalif (double [] calificaciones)
   {
       System.out.println("\nPromedio");
       for(int i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++)
       {
           //sumar, sacar y mostrar el promedio
       }
   }

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
       double [] calificaciones;
       int tam = 1;
       while(tam > 0)
       {
           System.out.print("\n Numero de calificaciones ");
           tam = lector.nextInt();
           if(tam > 0)
           {
               calificaciones = new double[tam];
               calificaciones = cargacalif(calificaciones);
               muestracalifs(calificaciones);
               sumacalif(calificaciones);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que hacer lo mismo que con papel y lápiz. Sumar todas las notas y luego dividir entre el número de notas.

Quizás no lo sepas porque estés empezando a programar:

- total += calificaciones[i] **es lo mismo que poner** total = total + calificaciones[i]

```
public static void sumacalif (double [] calificaciones)
   {
       System.out.println("\nPromedio");
       double total = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++)
       {
           total += calificaciones[i];
       }
       double promedio = total / calificaciones.length;
       System.out.print(promedio);
   }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Gonzalo, ya llevo un rato programando solo que tengo la cabeza en muchas cosas y me ciclo al momento que no sale a la primera, debería practicar mas.